# Generate colliders in Unity Import

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, fbx, mesh-collider

I created a model in blender and exported as fbx and then added the fbx file to unity. On generating colliders, unity distorted the model mesh so badly, that the collider wont fit.

Can someone help me or tell me what I am doing wrong. Is there a blender setting that I need to check before exporting?

Answer (score 1):

Check your export FBX export settings in blender. I've had the best luck with setting the scale according to what I used in Blender, using "selected objects" while selecting the objects I care about, and selecting the experimental "Apply modifiers" checkbox if I'm using any. Those have ended in the most correct results for me.